# Component within a component, or both components under a parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js in a project and I encountered a problem on how I should structure my components.

Suppose I have a **component1** (we'll call this one as **ItemView**) that shows the information on an item from a list of items, and **component2** (as **EditDialog**) that shows a modal to edit the item's information. I have 3 approaches in mind but I'm not sure which is the best approach in terms of readability, maintainability, scalability (and the like).

**1. Component2 within Component1**

For every instance of **ItemView**, there will be an **EditDialog** component.

**Parent component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <item-view
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
      :item="item"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**ItemView component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- show item information here -->
    <edit-dialog :item="item"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**2. Component1 and Component2 under the same Parent**

**ItemView** emits an event to edit the item.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <item-view
      v-for="item in items"
      :key="item.id"
      :item="item"
      @edit="editItem(item)"
    />
    <edit-dialog ref="editDialog"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ...

export default {
  components: { ... },
  data: () => { ... },
  methods: {
    editItem(item) {
      this.$refs.editDialog.edit(item)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**3. Using an EventBus**

This approach is similar with approach #2, but instead of using the **parent** component for component communication, an **EventBus** is used.

I am not sure which among these is the best approach to follow or if any of these approaches are right or wrong and there are better methods other than the ones above. If I were to choose, I'm leaning towards the first approach.

What is the best approach for this kind of problem or is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would said the one who suits the most to you and seems more maintenable.

Anyway, we have to keep in mind here that the edit-dialog mode is a overlayed modal of your webpage which is listing item-views. At this point, first solution isn't the good one for me, because the components edit-dialog would be repeated for each ItemView components, which is pointless because (I guess) we can't open more than one modal at the same time.

The second one is more suitable I think, and since the parent component is a kind of ItemWrapper / Manager, I don't see any problem to handle some event logic in here. Using an EventBus for this kind of feature that concerns two nearby UI components seems to me a bit exagerated.

On the performance side, I will let someone more experimented than me talk about it. Hope it helps.